# TYPO3 Backend Layout Organisation?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have a range of sites that use their own backend layouts. The problem is the BE layout list shows all the BE layouts for all the sites. Is there a way to just show the layouts intended for use with each site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible in the Page TSConfig. See the documentation [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/singlehtml/Index.html#backendlayout) or by the [Options](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/Options/Index.html)

The only thing you have to do to set this option value in the Page TSConfig:

```
options.backendLayout.exclude = <comma_separated_id_list>
```

Example:

```
options.backendLayout.exclude = 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you do exclude all, then include the ones you want? Otherwise every time a new backend layout is added you have to edit all existing sites...

Comment: To be honest, I don't know any setting to do it on the other way around, sorry :(

Comment: You can define the backend layouts by PageTS only. I suggest you go that road and only define the layouts for the pages you want. ``mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts...`` Use the ``Info`` module to analyze your current setup.

Comment: If you have too many BE layout, you may want to use gridelements instead. It is a more flexible way to manage different layouts. Generally then you have 1 column as a BE layout, and you can use different gridelements.